# I am using @SwimLineNgx-Chart Horizontal Stacked bar graph.The Chart Data Format is different from Api Response.How I can Map this any suggestion

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngx-charts

The following below is the Data format that Ngx-Chart is expecting for render;

```
ChartDataFormat=[
  {
        name:'First Item '
        series:[
            {
                name:'Availablity Loss' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Slow Cycle' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Ideal Cyle' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Performance Loss' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Small Stop' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            }
        ]
    },
        {
        name:'Second Item'
        series:[
            {
                name:'Availablity Loss' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Slow Cycle' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Ideal Cyle' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Performance Loss' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            },
            {
                name:'Small Stop' //activity
                value:'1200' //duration
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

**Response I am getting from the Api is following**

```
var ApiResponse = [
  {
    "activity": "Stand By",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:06:21.770407",
    "duration": 522.3547,
    "counterValue": 0
  },
  {
    "activity": "Ideal Cycle",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:06:22.275242",
    "duration": 0.504835,
    "counterValue": 1
  },
  {
    "activity": "Slow Cycle",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:06:49.310398",
    "duration": 27.035156,
    "counterValue": 2
  },
  {
    "activity": "Ideal Cycle",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:07:36.136659",
    "duration": 46.826263,
    "counterValue": 4
  },
  {
    "activity": "Availability Loss",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:09:01.920427",
    "duration": 85.78377,
    "counterValue": 5
  },
  {
    "activity": "Ideal Cycle",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:09:24.20074",
    "duration": 22.280313,
    "counterValue": 6
  },
  {
    "activity": "Slow Cycle",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:10:15.615391",
    "duration": 51.41465,
    "counterValue": 8
  },
  {
    "activity": "Ideal Cycle",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:10:39.174414",
    "duration": 23.559023,
    "counterValue": 9
  },
  {
    "activity": "Availability Loss",
    "endTime": "2020-08-13T19:12:09.1893",
    "duration": 90.014885,
    "counterValue": 10
  },
  .....................
]
```

I am trying with the following code but the problem is I don't know how to check that the series already have an item inside it or I am doing it wrong;

**The chartDataModel I am using it for**

```
export class ChartDataModel {
    public data: SerieModel[];
    constructor(data:  SerieModel[]) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

export class SerieModel {
    public name: string;
    public series: SeriersChildModel[];
    constructor(name:  string, series: SeriersChildModel[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }
}

export class SeriersChildModel {
    public name: string;
    public value: number;
    constructor(name:  string, value: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I am doing inside the component in following way;

```
export class LiveViewComponent  implements OnInit {

  multi: any[] = [];
  view: any[] = [900, 400];
  ngxData: ChartDataModel = {
    data: [
      {
        name: 'Series 1',
        series: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Series 2',
        series: []
      }
    ]
  };
  constructor(private productionLocationSvc: ProductionMonitoringService) {
    console.log(this.ngxData.data);
    Object.assign(this.ngxData);
  }
  // options
  showXAxis: boolean = true;
  showYAxis: boolean = true;
  gradient: boolean = true;
  showLegend: boolean = true;
  showXAxisLabel: boolean = true;
  yAxisLabel: string = 'Workstations';
  showYAxisLabel: boolean = true;
  xAxisLabel: string = '';
  showDataLabel: boolean = true;
  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['red', 'green', 'orange']
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMonitoringData();
  }
  getMonitoringData() {
    this.productionLocationSvc.getMonitoringData().subscribe(response => {
      let currData;
      response.map((p) => {
            **How to convert this into ChartDataForm,Please see above ChartDataFormat**
         console.log(p);
        this.ngxData.data[0].series.push({ name:p.activity, value: p.duration});
        this.ngxData.data[1].series.push({ name:p.activity, value: p.activity})
      });
      this.ngxData.data = [...this.ngxData.data];
    },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```